# Wireless Connection Suddenly Not Working

Tags: wireless

My wireless connection suddenly stopped working for a particular network. It worked fine until today, no change to the network, my other devices can connect. It is a wifi that uses PEAP and MSCHAPv2. 
If i can post any outputs let me know.
Thanks
James

Comment: Regardless of other devices, reboot the AP and try again.

Comment: I tried this as well as restarting network manager.

Comment: If it doesn't work with only one network then reason tells us the problem is with that network.

Comment: But it is only my lenovo thinkpad that will not work on the network.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Does it work with others? If so it should be fine (but you may want to delete that network's profile and connect it again).

Comment: I have deleted and tried to add again. It just keeps asking for a password and won't connect. Other devices connect to the network without problem

Comment: That seems to be related with improper WiFi settings: Use WPA2-AES only, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Again, *regardless of other devices*. I wouldn't have started my first comment with that sentence if i wasn't aware of that so no need to repeat yourself. And next time please explain *in the question itself* what the problem actually is.

Comment: The WiFi security drop down box only has "WPA & WPA2 enterprise"

Comment: What device is that exactly?

Comment: Its a thinkpad e450. I have been running Ubuntu for 12 months without problems.

Comment: By device I meant whatever is managing the WiFi, not the clients...

Comment: I don't know what sort of equipment is installed in the office. I use the default that came with Ubuntu, network manager.

Comment: Well, the changes I mentioned above are to be made at that router. If you have no access to or aren't authorized to make changes, there's nothing I or we can help you with. And this is not a Ubuntu question. Please understand Linux is usually more strict about WiFi security. Something changed at that router if it was working before. The new settings aren't compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I think its likely you are wrong.

Comment: No, it actually isn't likely that I'm wrong, at all. Unlike you, I have LOTS of experience with wireless networks and the suggested settings above pretty much everybody in the business knows. If your IT department does otherwise, they're wrong and the result of that you already know. Try to convince then to adhere to the "best practices" that in this case should be the only practices.